# Открытие Google Play по кнопке

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Требуется по нажатию по кнопке открыть страницу приложения в приложении Google Play. Можно открыть таким способом:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.author.app"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Но тогда выскакивает выбор приложения, которым открыть: маркет, стандартный браузер, браузер опера. Вопрос: Можно ли принудительно указать, чтоб ссылка открывалась именно в приложении Google Play? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл:

> [android launch market intent](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20launch%20market%20intent)

2. Идём по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070/3212712)
3. Копируем код:

   ```
   final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
   try {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
   } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
   }
   ```

Comment: И снова большое Вам спасибо! Я искал по гуглу, правда писал по русски запрос, ничего толкового небыло.

Comment: @Pollux, не удивительно что не нашли. Все общение на эти темы и вся документация на английском. Большая часть обучения разработке - обучение правильно гуглить.

Comment: @DanielShatz, согласен с Вами